# Automatic signatures in Emails with Access-Outlook macros

Tags: string, vba, email, ms-access, outlook

I'm trying to put together a mass-email macro which will iterate through a table, pulling emails and recipient names. For branding purposes, I would like to send each email with signatures.

I'm trying to use the MailItem object but I keep running into 2 problems:

1. .display creates a new outlook email and populates it with the default signature. However, .body will wipe the signature with the text string in strMessage. I'm guessing its because I can't have both a table (incl. pictures, etc) and strings in the same email object?
2. I've tried the .send and .body method on both Microsoft Outlook 15 and 16 Object libraries. While both work on 16, neither seem to exist in 15. I am always given an "Application-defined or Object-defined error". I can't find any documentation regarding Outlook 15 libraries, does anyone know what methods 15 has equivalent to .send and .body?

   ```
   Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String
   Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)

   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
   Dim db As Database
   Dim strSQL As String, strFirstName As String, strLastName As String, strFullName As String, strSubject As String, strMessage As String

   Set db = CurrentDb

   strSQL = "SELECT Email, FirstName, LastName FROM PersonsT WHERE [PersonsT]![Attended]=True"

   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

   Do While Not rs.EOF
   strFirstName = rs.Fields("FirstName")
   strLastName = rs.Fields("LastName")
   strFullName = rs.Fields("FirstName") & " " & rs.Fields("LastName")

   strSubject = "Greetings"
   strMessage = "Hello " & strFullName & vbNewLine & vbCrLf & " Let me be the first to congratulate you on registering in this program"

   With OMail
   .Display
   End With

   With OMail        
       .to = rs![Email]
       .Subject = strSubject
       .body = strMessage
       .send     
   End With

   rs.MoveNext
       Loop

           Set OMail = Nothing
           Set OApp = Nothing

           rs.Close
           Set rs = Nothing
   ```

Comment: Try  `.body = strMessage & vbCrLf &  .body`

Comment: If your Outlook has multiple signature files to choose from, create Word App, use `oWordApp.EmailOptions.EmailSignature.NewMessageSignature = <SignatureFilename>` to alter the signature and/or to restore original one. Do this before the Outlook App to send will use html signatures which can have images and contents in table etc.

Comment: @TimWilliams No luck. I tried isolating .body and it is also producing an Application-defined or Object-defined error.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using MailItem's [GetInspector()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868098.aspx) property to retrieve signature text beforehand and then concatenate to message body. Rendering may vary so try `.HTMLBody` over `.Body` in both lines:

```
...
Dim signature As String

oMail.GetInspector
signature = oMail.Body

With OMail        
    .Recipients.Add rs![Email]
    .Subject = strSubject
    .Body = strMessage & signature
    .Display     
End With
```

Comment: Hi there. This code works on my machine with library 16, but on 15, it still produces an Application-defined or Object-defined error.

Comment: Outlook 2013 corresponds to version 15 and Outlook 2016 to version 16. Do you have both Outlook versions dual-installed? I only have 2013 installed, so I assure you this works in 15.

Comment: I have Office 2016 installed on another machine and am testing the code in in parallel with my main machine with Office 2013. Does the .send function work on your 2013 based machine also?

Comment: Yes, `.Send` works. Apart from this does any mail run from MS Access? Maybe you need to repair Outlook.

Comment: SendObject is fully functional but unfortunately it can't populate the signature. I've tried the code on a couple of my colleague's PCs as well with no success so I don't think it could just be my Outlook libraries acting up. I'll ask our IT guy and see if he knows something we're not taking into account.

Comment: MS Access' `SendObject` is entirely different than Outlook's `MailItem.Send`. Does `Display` as this solution uses show signature? I can assure you this answer should work in rendering signature with body. Maybe your issue involves Exchange accounts, firewall, or Office365 config.

Answer (score 0):

This works with all sorts of flavours of outlook, and uses late binding so versions / references shouldn't be an issue.

```
Dim OutApp          As Object
Dim OutMail         As Object
Dim signature       As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail                               ' This creates a blank email and captures the users default signature.
    .BodyFormat = 2                        'olFormatHTML
    .Display
End With

signature = OutMail.HTMLBody
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I completely missed this response. I was using Outlook applications in an earlier version of this macro but found that setting any sort of .body (which would be entered in plain text I believe) would wipe the signature. I think it's because the signature has tables within it.